# Multilist with Search exclude items named with wildcard

Tags: content-search

I am trying to use multilist with search  to allow the editor to select any item except home and items named with *

I am basically using * as described [here](https://sitecorerocksblog.wordpress.com/2016/11/15/resolve-wildcard-item/)

Since this is not a real page I want to filter it out but as soon as I enter

```
StartSearchLocation={F9045E60-5D2A-477B-8D10-7C8C83684260}&Filter=_path:C096F4EBC9C6402B897481CEF12D7EFD|-_name:Home|-name:*
```

I only get the home page I have tried escapeing * with \ but that didn't work any insight into this woudl be great thanks.

Comment: Crossposting. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50067457/multilist-with-search-exclude-items-named-with-wildcard